# Mongoose many-to-many with three schemas

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, feathersjs

Many-to-many between two models are simple and well documented, but I cannot find anything about my case.

I have a user, organization, role.
The user belongs to many organizations and can have multiple roles within each organization.

How would I model it with mongoose so I can then easily find user's memberships etc?

I am going to use it with feathers js but fundamentally it shouldn't make any difference I think.

Comment: in your organization collection create a role prop witch has array of objects, each object has a name(the role name) and array of users ids.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this giving weightage to userschema,  having array of  organisation objects with all role ids.

Organisation:

```
[{
  id:
  name:
  ...
}]
```

Roles:

```
[{
  id:
  role:
  ...
}]
```

Users:

```
[{
  id:   
  details : [{
     organisationId:
     roleIds:[]
     ...
  }]
  ...
}]
```